# How can I create special search with check/uncheck image field in filter criteria of views

Tags: 8, search

How can I create special search with check/uncheck image field in filter certia of views module in drupal 8 ?

I want if users check image field checkbox and click on "go" button , they whatch only content that have image and when uncheck that they can watch all content .

Comment: You might need to write custom code for this functionality.

Comment: This isn't the platform for tutorials. If you can't find a contributed module that provides this functionality then you should search for a guide on building views plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need [BEF](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module to get exactly what you want, **but it's not ready yet**.

**The workaround:**
Although Drupal still has a query checkbox value bug (pretty ugly:(), there is a workaround and you can come up with the following close solution:

1. Create a new filter criteria
2. Choose your image field "target_id" property.
3. Configuring the filtering critera check "Expose this filter to visitors"
4. Choose "Grouped filters"
5. Mark "Optional" checkbox.
6. Widget type: radios.
7. Allow multiple selections.
8. Mark the first grouping (Grouping 1), give it a label and choose operator "Is not empty(NOT NULL).

You are now half way through. Altough it's working like this in view preview mode, it won't on the real page (because of the bug above).

Now you need to write a hook_form_FORM_ID_alter in one of your .module file, mine's looks like this:

```
function base_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-search-page-1') {
    $request = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->query->all();
    $filter_identifier = 'field_image_target_id';
    if (!$request[$filter_identifier]) {
      $user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
      unset($user_input[$filter_identifier]);
      $form_state->setUserInput($user_input);
    }
  }
}
```

WHERE:

"views_exposed_form" => form_id (you will get the same, but check it)
"views-exposed-form-search-page-1" => is the '#id' parameter of your form. (this will be probably different)
"field_image_target_id" => This is your filter identifier, which can be found (also renamed) in when clicking on views this filter criteria.